# Multiple applications inside a Django project

Tags: python-3.x, django, postgresql

I am creating an ERP web application using Django. How can i connect multiple apps inside of a project with one database. I am using the PostgreSQL database and also how can i centralized the database for all modules of ERP. How can i perform operations in other module and see if user is authenticated or not

Comment: if you have many apps in one project, all of them will be connected to a database that you configure in setting.py.

Comment: all apps in the project by default use one database.

Comment: Django use SQLite 3 as default database. I change db from SQLite 3 to PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0):

Your apps use only the database(s) set up in your settings.py file.

Comment: i set up only on db for all my apps, So now my db is centralized?

Comment: Something like that.  They all use one database